# get some content in file_get_content function

Tags: php, html

I use `file_get_content` to get content of a website. This gets all the content but I only need content in `<div class="nomal">` tag in content I get. It have some `<div class="nomal">` tag I need get all `<div class="nomal">` tag. My function:

```
function get_need_content($str, $strstart, $strend){
    $new_startstr = strpos($str, $strstart);
    $new_strend = strpos($str, $strend);
    echo $final_str=substr($str, $new_startstr, $new_strend );
}
```

this function only get one in all `<div class="nomal">` tag. I need to get all.

Comment: You can use a DOM parser, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off using [`SimpleXML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) with an XPath query to pull all instances of  the tag you want:

```
$str = '
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
  </body>
</html>
';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//p') as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific tag in the return from file_get_content, you can either run a preg_match to get the value that you are looking for, or because you say it is a website you can load the site as a SimpleXMLElement or DOMDocument to get the value of a specific tag.